# DRM Videos On VideoView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I want to play WVM videos on my Application. I am using WideWine DRM plugin for that.

The Videos getting License successfully and running fine, 
But When I move the SeekBar of MediaController from current position to any position, It throws a MediaPlayer error sometime.

The error is like :

```
MediaPlayer error (260, -2001)
```

What are the actual cause for this error ?

I have used this code to start video :

```
wv = new WidevineDrmHandler();
wv.initialize(MainActivity.this);
wv.requireLicence(url, handler2, false);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
mVideoView.start();
```